# Не отображать в url предыдущий state или поменять states местами

Tags: angularjs

У меня есть 3х уровневые стейты

```
$stateProvider
  .state('index', {
    url: '',
    controller: 'MainCtrl'
  })
  .state('index.name', {
    url: '/:name',
    views: {
      '@': {
        templateUrl: 'app/names/name.html',
        controller: 'NameCtrl'
      }
    }
  })
  .state('index.name.page', {
    url: '/:number',
    templateUrl: 'app/pages/page.html',
    controller: 'PageCtrl'
  })
```

и на последнем стейте url выглядит так - `site.com/Josh/123`. Можно ли упустить поменять для отображения стейты местами `site.com/123/John.

```
$stateProvider
  .state('index', {
    url: '',
    controller: 'MainCtrl'
  })
  .state('index.name', {
    url: '/:name',
    views: {
      '@': {
        templateUrl: 'app/names/name.html',
        controller: 'NameCtrl'
      }
    }
  })
  .state('index.name.page', {
    url: '/:number/:name',
    templateUrl: 'app/pages/page.html',
    controller: 'PageCtrl'
  })
```

Если роутинг поменять на такой - то я получу то что мне нужно, но предыдущий все еще будет тянутся и выходит `site.com/Josh/123/Josh`.

Дело в том что номер страницы может идти только после выбора страницы у пользователя, поэтому в роутинге поменять очередность к сожалению не вариант :(

Comment: А зачем в 3 стейте (`index.name.page`) его расширяете? Проще же указать как отдельный стейт `index.someState` и должно все работать.

Comment: просто по вложенности так выходит, тк в index.name внутри отрисовывается index.name.page.
например у меня страница, с боку (слева) меню, где мы выбираем юзеров и там их имена по списку. справа же отрисовываем контент, для юзера на которого нажали. в итоге index.name.page зависит от index.name и мы просто так не сможем сделать отдельный стейт